# Is it possible to test consumer side without stub runner in spring-cloud-contract

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Currently I want to test the error handling of calling other micro services in consumer side via spring cloud contract. But there are some troubles blocking me to create stubs in provider side due to it's difficult to share build artifacts in docker CI build.

I'm wondering if possible to just create groovy or yaml contacts in consumer side then using them by wiremock server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to achieve it. One, is to clone the producer's code, run `./mvnw clean install -DskipTests` or `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal -x test` and have the stubs installed without running any tests. Another option is to write your own `StubDownloaderBuilder` (for Finchley) that will fetch the contracts via Aether as the `AetherStubDownloader` does, but then will also automatically convert the contracts to WIreMock stubs.

Of course both approaches are "cheating". You shouldn't use the stubs in your CI system until the producer has actually published the stubs.

Maybe instead of hacking the system it's better to analyze

> provider side due to it's difficult to share build artifacts in docker CI build.

and try to fix it? Why is it difficult? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: We are doing CI build in gitlab pipeline, which uses docker image to do gradle build. It's impossible to share the gradle caches due to [well known issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/851#issuecomment-364150582). Looks like it blocks sharing stubs via local install artifacts in gradle/maven caches. Publishing the stubs to remote repo might be a solution, it will require more infra support.

Comment: You can use maven publish to publish to a maven repo and then reference that repo. You can attach that repo as a volume maybe?